# PostGIS make line from shortest distance from points to polygons

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, linestring

I have two tables. An exploded points parcels layer

```
create table a as
select id, (ST_Dumppoints(geom)).geom as geom FROM tableblah;
```

and another parcels table call it b which is a polygon

I wrote a a query that calculates the shortest distance from the exploded parcels/as points to layer b

```
select id,min(st_distance(a.geom,b.geom)) as min_distance
    from a join b on a.id = b.id group by a.id
```

Now I want to be able to create that minimum line from the points to the parcel. I am unsure how to format this part. I know I probably need st_makeline.

should I convert the layer b parcels to points as well?

UPDATE

I converted layer b too a points also

```
create table b_points as
select b.id,(ST_Dumppoints(geom)).geom as geom from b;
```

then i ran

```
select distinct on(a.id) a.id, st_makeline(a.geom,b_points.geom) as geom
from a join b_points on a.id = b_points.id order by 
a.id,st_distance(a.geom,b.geom)
```

this gives me this which is somewhat correct, but the parcel I converted to points only produced 4 points...

[image]

ANSWERED:

ended up using st_shortestline too replace my use of st_makeline. I converted both my polygon parcels table to lines and ran it.as you can see below the results from using st_shortestline is more accurate than st_makeline in regards to finding the shortest path from the parcels boundaries

[image]

Comment: would ST_ClosestPoint work?

Comment: in place of st_makeline?

Comment: wouldnt it need to be aggregated? that seems to be my problem and I cant figure out the logic for a subquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ST_Shortestline is for that purpose
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ShortestLine.html

ST_Closestpoint is actually a wrapper around ST_Shortestline

Comment: Worth noting that this differs from what OP has done so far in that actually finds the closest point on the edge of the geometry, not just the closest vertex. (IMO this is better, but I guess it depends on what exactly is being modelled.)

Comment: I thought that was the problem of OP to find points between the vertex points.

Comment: Oh I see from the angels of the lines that they will more or less connect to the vertex points anyway.

Comment: ended up using st_shortestline too replace my use of st_makeline. and I did lines to lines, that got me the best result

Comment: @NicklasAvén can you recommend any resources(aside from the regular postgis doc) that will help me better understand how the two functions work?

Comment: Well, I wrote some blog post long time ago about them after I wrote the functions. But I am afraid that blog is not online now.

Comment: But the idea is quite simple. Using ST_Distance you get a distance. Between what points is that distance calculated? That is what you get from ST_Shortestline.The length of the shortest line is exacly the same as the answer from ST_Distance

Comment: So, ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(a,b) = ST_Distance(a,b)

Comment: And ST_ClosestPoint is just the first point in the shortestline.